# Chrome flip touch on rotated container (inverse touch scroll)

Tags: google-chrome, electron, google-chrome-devtools

I have a touchscreen (or can be proof with touch emulator in developer console of chrome).

On web site there is embedded iframe, which is rotated via css by wrapping container.

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

1. If you try **swipe up** (touch scroll) over the iframe, the content of iframe is scrolled into opposite of swipe - is **scrolled down**.
2. If there is no rotation transform applied, swipe works fine, swipe up = content scroll up, swipe down = content scroll down.

**Simplified example of this behaviour here:** https://codepen.io/mitotvpha/pen/abymbWd

Doe's it possible to fix this inverting swipe behaviour somehow via css or by setting up the chromium core? Or any other solution?

Note: Setting up of chromium will be solution for me too, because the behaviour is the same on electron app, which runs this core.

Thanks for any hints!

**EDIT:**
This problem seems to be general problem with touch action in chrome and according to comment [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1262125#c5) is unaware of transformation.

Comment: This seems like bug in chromium core. I have already reported it to chromium issue tracker. You can track the progress here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715148